# How to change the SQL Server Backup file (.bak) file default icon?

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, windows-server, format

As I would like to say that by mistake the SQL Server 2012 backup file (`.bak`) open with **`wordpad`**. Due to this reason all backup files of SQL Server (.bak) file change with **`wordpad`** icon in entire the `Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit` O.S.

Now the SQL Server (.bak) file icon looks like as attached below:

[image]

**To Verify the Backup File through Restore Headeronly TSQL Command**

As per MSDN BOL documentation [RESTORE Statements - HEADERONLY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I have checked the `Restore Headeronly from Disk`  from verification of my (`.bak`) file. The

I have checked and verify through the Restore Headeronly TSQL command. The result set returned by RESTORE HEADERONLY includes a row for each of these other backup sets.

I am also attaching that screen shot for persual.

[image]

It seems to odd the icon format of SQL Server (`.bak)` file. The (.bak) file icon format through out the Server has been changed with (wordpad) icon.

> **My Question is that**: How to revert back the (**`.bak`**) file with
>   their default icon format? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Just press shift-->right click file --> open with --> choose default program and associate ssns with .bak file.

Comment: As an aside, few programs actually care what the extension of the file is, that is mostly a convenience factor.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10

1. Right click on the .bak file
2. Choose properties
3. On the General tab, click the **Change...** button next to Opens with:
   [image]
4. Under **Other Options** choose **More apps** 
   [image]
5. Scroll to the bottom and click **Look for another app on this PC**
   [image]
6. Go the location of **Ssms.exe**.  Mine was located here:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio
7. Choose **Ssms.exe**
8. Click the **Open** button and then the **Save** button

It should now be associated with SQL Server Management Studio and have the icon you'd like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 click the “Start” button and select “Control Panel.”

2 Click “Programs,” click “Default Programs”

3 Select “Set Default Programs.”

4 On the left of the screen is a list of all programs installed on your computer.

5 Click the program you want to associate with a particular file type

6 Click “Choose Defaults for this program.” Place check marks next to each of the file types you want to associate with the selected program

7 click the “Save” button.

**Source:**

https://superuser.com/questions/127889/remove-default-open-with-setting